# css loads background image in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have developed one website which run smoothly in chrome. but it has issue in firefox. It wont able to load the background image. I don't understand why this happen.Please Checkout in chrome and firefox

**CSS**

```
#background {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url("../img/bg/photo_bg.jpg") 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Could you make that a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so we can run it right here from your question? Also see [mcve] on the topic.

Comment: Add left: 0, top:0, width: 100vw, height: 100vh. Should work.

Comment: This works fine for me in both browsers: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/yaae1fh3/

Comment: same as @StanGeorge I'm also add top and left to 0 then background appeared. I was guessing that maybe the chrome problem, cos sometimes it smart enough to automatically default some attribute, but firefox won't.

Comment: top and left 0 works for me. i am also thinking how this happen. thanks @Anami for explanation and stan georage as well

Comment: check codepen its working fine in both browser

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the `display: inline-block` property itseems to work on both Chrome & FF.

```
background {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background: url("../img/bg/photo_bg.jpg") 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* display: inline-block; -- remove this */
}
```

There seems to be no other difference if you remove the property, so was there a reason why it was used in the first place?

Also just a note, I noticed there was a `media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), not all, not all` rule used which effects ONLY the chrome/safari browsers.

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), not all, not all {
  #background {
    background: url(../img/bg/photo_bg_%402X.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

Comment: its even better solution thanks @Nikhil. for explanation. Now i know exactly whats was the issue.

Comment: No problem @Darshan, you could mark the answer so it can help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the display to "block".
It should be working with that.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a solution description here. Posting a 
Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Examplethat demonstrates 
your solution. Thanks :-) !

Comment: Sure, I just set the display to block in the inspector and didn't have time to do more since I'm at work, sorry.